# Infinite product with the Catalan numbers

Tags: numerics, special-functions, products

During the analysis of OEIS sequence [A179381](http://oeis.org/A179381) I got the following expression with an infinite product:

$$\prod _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(1-4^{-k} C_{k-1}\right)$$

```
 N[Product[1 - CatalanNumber[k-1]/4^k, {k, 1, Infinity}]]

 (* 0.582348 *)
```

How to calculate this infinite product with higher precision ?
With N[..., 10] I got an error message

```
 (* NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections... *)
```

I will get the same error message after the transformation to an infinite sum

```
 N[Exp[Sum[Log[1 - CatalanNumber[k-1]/4^k], {k, 1, Infinity}]], 10]
```

Does anyone have any idea how to calculate more decimal places?

Comment: This seems to be very slowly convergent. When I manually performed Wynn $\varepsilon$ on your product with 250 digit precision, I was only able to manage the result `0.5829`.

Comment: `NProduct[1 - CatalanNumber[k - 1]/4^k, {k, 1, Infinity}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 20]` yields `0.582348`, but with the warning that "NIntegrate failed to converge". Perhaps increasing `MaxRecursion`? (as in `NProduct[1 - CatalanNumber[k - 1]/4^k, {k, 1, Infinity}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 20, Method -> {NIntegrate, MaxRecursion -> 25}]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Progress can be made by summing the logs of the terms in the product,

```
Exp@NSum[Log[1 - CatalanNumber[k - 1]/4^k], {k, 1, Infinity}]
```

This, in itself, gives the same result as in the question, `0.582348`.  Moreover, attempting to improve precision by means of the ideas suggested by [AccidentalFourierTransform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34893/accidentalfouriertransform) in a comment above are no more successful than they were for `NProduct`.  However, because the terms in the sum approach zero for large `k`, the terms can be approximated there by

```
s = Series[Log[1 - CatalanNumber[k - 1]/4^k], {k, Infinity, 8}] // Normal
(* -17/(1024 k^5 π) - 3/(128 k^4 π) - 1/(32 k^3 π) - 25/(512 k^(7/2) Sqrt[π]) 
   - 3/(32 k^(5/2) Sqrt[π]) - 1/(4 k^(3/2) Sqrt[π]) *)
```

plus many more smaller terms (which are not discarded in the actual computation).

Comparing `s` with the summand at `k == 10^4` shows good agreement.

```
N[(Log[1 - CatalanNumber[k - 1]/4^k] - s) /. k -> 10^4, 50]
(* -1.5905675495607351158866494466074940463334600411045*10^-37 *)
```

So, use this approximation to perform the summation for `k > 10^4`.

```
suml = NSum[s, {k, 10^4 + 1, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 16, Method -> {NIntegrate, MaxRecursion -> 25}]
(* -0.00282091270584364563 *)
```

The sum for smaller `k` can, in principle, be performed by `NSum` using brute force, but it is quite slow.  Instead, use

```
FunctionExpand[CatalanNumber[k - 1]/4^k]
(* Gamma[-(1/2) + k]/(4 Sqrt[π] Gamma[1 + k]) *)
```

which can be summed much more rapidly.

```
sums = NSum[Log[1 - Gamma[-(1/2) + k]/(4 Sqrt[π] Gamma[1 + k])], {k, 1, 10^4}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 16]
(* -0.5378660936971350 *)
```

Finally,

```
Exp[suml + sums]
(* 0.58234803808391506 *)
```

with an accuracy of about sixteen significant figures.  Greater precision can be obtained in a similar manner, although the computations are likely to be much slower.